# Passing dynamic order by in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am creating below stored procedure.

```
declare @PageNum as Int
declare @PerPageResult as Int
declare @StartDate as varchar(25)
declare @EndDate as varchar(25)
declare @SortType as Varchar(50)
declare @SortDirection as Varchar(4)
set @PageNum=1
set @PerPageResult=20
set @StartDate='2008-02-08'
set @EndDate='2015-02-08'
set @SortType='RegDate'
set @SortDirection='Desc'
declare @Temp Table(RowNum int, RegDate Date, Registered int, Female int, Male int, [Join] int, Rebill int, TotalPointsEarned int, Expire int)
declare @sort varchar(50)
Insert into @Temp
    Select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by @SortType+' '+@SortDirection) As RowNum, * From (    
    SELECT 
    CAST(m.registrationdate AS Date) as RegDate,    
    count(m.id) Registered,
    count(CASE WHEN m.gender='F' then 'F' end) As Female,
    count(CASE WHEN m.gender='M' then 'M' end) As Male
    count(CASE WHEN p.paymenttransactiontype='N' then 'N' end) As [Join],
    count(CASE WHEN p.paymenttransactiontype='R' then 'R' end) As Rebill,
    count(m.tokensearned) As TotalPointsEarned,
    count(CASE WHEN p.paymenttransactiontype='E' then 'E' end) As Expire
    from member m
    join payment p on m.id=p.id_member
    join user_role u on u.member_id=m.id
    where u.role_id <> 3
    and CAST(m.registrationdate AS Date) > @StartDate and CAST(m.registrationdate AS Date) < @EndDate
    GROUP BY CAST(m.registrationdate AS Date)
    ) as aa 
    Select * from @Temp Where RowNum>((@PageNum-1)*@PerPageResult) and RowNum<=@PerPageResult * @PageNum
    Order by @SortType+' '+@SortDirection
```

In above when i pass the `Order by` clause dynamically, its not sorting the data properly but when i write column name explicitly, it works fine. Might be its taking `@SortType+' '+@SortDirection` as `varchar` rather than `Date`

I tried writing `Order by case when (@Sort='RegDate' and @SortDirection='Desc') Then RegDate End Desc`, but it didn't work

How can i pass order by dynamically here.

Edit:
@Andomar: I tried your provided solution and added one more field for Date type. And it didn't work too.

below is what i did.

```
create table t1 (id int, name varchar(50), dt date);
insert t1 values 
    (1, 'Chihiro Ogino','2009-02-08'), 
    (2, 'Spirit of the Kohaku River','2008-02-08'), 
    (3, 'Yubaba','2012-02-08');



declare @sortColumn varchar(50) = 'dt'
declare @sortOrder varchar(50) = 'ASC'

select  *
from    t1
order by
        case
        when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0
        when @sortColumn = 'id' then id
        end ASC
,       case
        when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then ''
        when @sortColumn = 'name' then name
        end ASC
,       case
        when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then ''
        when @sortColumn = 'dt' then name
        end ASC
,       case
        when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0
        when @sortColumn = 'id' then id
        end DESC
,       case
        when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then ''
        when @sortColumn = 'name' then name
        end DESC
,       case
        when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then ''
        when @sortColumn = 'dt' then name
        end DESC
```

Comment: gender='SH': haven't seen that before...

Comment: @MitchWheat: Ignore it :P

Comment: search for "ORDER BY CASE"

Comment: instead of case, do we have better solution as i have 11 columns for sort type.

Comment: Or, sort on the client! It's so much easier!

Comment: @archangel76: Sorting on client side won't help, suppose you have 10000 records in database and you're showing 10 at a time. Clientside sort would occur in those 10 records only which is even not correct.

Comment: Very true. I found this question looking for just the sort, not the pagination, and realized that sorting in the .NET code was actually what I needed, and that was sufficient.  The question didn't help me, and so I was posting to help those that only needed the sort and had run across this. Sorry I was previously unclear.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use a complicated `order by` clause.  That requires one `case` for each sort direction and each data type.  With this example dataset:

```
create table t1 (id int, name varchar(50), created date);
insert t1 values 
    (1, 'Chihiro Ogino', '2012-01-01'), 
    (2, 'Spirit of the Kohaku River', '2012-01-03'), 
    (3, 'Yubaba', '2012-01-02');
```

You could use an `order by` clause like:

```
declare @sortColumn varchar(50) = 'created'
declare @sortOrder varchar(50) = 'DESC'

select  *
from    t1
order by
        case
        when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0
        when @sortColumn = 'id' then id
        end ASC
,       case
        when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then ''
        when @sortColumn = 'name' then name
        end ASC
,       case
        when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then cast(null as date)
        when @sortColumn = 'created' then created
        end ASC
,       case
        when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0
        when @sortColumn = 'id' then id
        end DESC
,       case
        when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then ''
        when @sortColumn = 'name' then name
        end DESC
,       case
        when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then cast(null as date)
        when @sortColumn = 'created' then created
        end DESC
```

[Working example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0a212/1/0)

Another option is to create the query dynamically, and run it with `exec`.  For example:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select * from YourTable order by ' + @sortColumn + ' ' + @sortDir
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: instead of case, do we have better solution as i have 11 columns for sort type.

Comment: I tried writing Order by case when (@Sort='RegDate' and @SortDirection='Desc') Then RegDate End Desc, but it didn't work

Comment: @JitendraPancholi: That should work, if the variables are set correctly.

Comment: you can check in my query above. Its not sorting properly.

Comment: Can you please add 1 more column of date type and add sorting for that also and check. It won't work.

Comment: [New example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8891b/3/0) with multiple columns and multiple data types (a separate `case` is required for each data type and each sort order.  Dynamic SQL is a bit simpler I'd think.)

Comment: Let me check, and dynamic sql would be a performance issue..don't you think.

Comment: Quite the opposite, dynamic SQL is usually best for performance.  It makes the `order by` clause much simpler.  For a date column, make sure the type is correct.  Try `...   when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then cast(null as datetime) ...`

Comment: Yeah, got it. its working now. thanx. And one more thing, dynamic sql never compiles and its not good for performance.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi: Dynamic SQL **is** compiled and its query plan is reused whenever you run the exact same query.  This is actually an advantage: compiling a specific plan for each query is often better than running a generic plan that handles all cases.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25136/discussion-between-andomar-and-jitendra-pancholi)

Comment: It should be noted that **dynamic SQL is an injection vulnerability**. Don't use dynamic SQL if the parameter is controlled by the client. Even if it's just a multiple choice, if the string is what is sent from the client, they can use a custom POST to change the string that is sent up.

Comment: This article explains all the options and I learned a LOT (things I didn't know to ask) from this article: The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL by MVP Erland Sommarskog. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: I used this to simplify a large Entity Framework query by doing the filtering, sorting and OFFSET/FETCH NEXT-based pagination in an SQL function, then loading the objects with EF based on the returned primary keys. One thing to note with that approach: Include a ROW_NUMBER() over the same ORDER BY clause in your return values and use it to order the objects.

Comment: Is it not recomanded to turn the sp into a table function ? Table functions act as ordinery tables

Answer (score 1):

@Andomar's answer help solve a similar issue. I needed to sort on any number of 23 different columns, in any order. I ended up with the following:

```
create table sorting(ID int, columnName varchar(50), sort varchar(10), position int)
insert into sorting 
values(1,'column1','DESC',1),
      (1,'column2','ASC',2),
      ...              
      (1,'columnN','DESC',N)
```

Adding parameter @sort to the SP to identify the entries in sorting:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + a.columnName + ' ' +  a.sort 
                    FROM sorting a
                    WHERE a.ID = @sort
                    ORDER BY a.position ASC
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),NULL)
```

Comment: Good idea for sorting with multiple columns

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic approaches to building dynamically orderable stored procedures:

1. Pass in the `ORDER BY` clause as a parameter to the stored procedure. In the stored procedure, build up the SQL statement in a string and then execute this statement using `EXEC` or `sp_ExecuteSql`.

   ```
   -- This Method is used when your Column names are dynamic 
   -- We need to create a dynamic query and Execute it as shown below.

   CREATE PROCEDURE getEmployees ( @OrderByClause varchar(100) ) AS

   -- Create a variable @SQLStatement
   DECLARE @SQLStatement varchar(255)

   -- Enter the dynamic SQL statement into the
   -- variable @SQLStatement
   SELECT @SQLStatement =  'SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, SSN, Salary  
    FROM Employees ORDER BY '+ @OrderByClause+''

   -- Execute the SQL statement
   EXEC(@SQLStatement)
   ```
2. Pass in the column to sort by and then use a `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY` clause to order the results according to the input parameter value.

   ```
   --This method is used when you column name is not dynamic 

   SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, SSN, Salary
   FROM Employees
   ORDER BY
     CASE WHEN @ColumnName='LastName' THEN LastName
          WHEN @ColumnName='Salary' THEN CONVERT(varchar(50), Salary)
          WHEN @ColumnName='SSN' THEN SSN
     END
   ```

Comment: You should at least site this is from http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/010704-1.shtml

Comment: Incomplete, Haven't Explained Dynamic Sorting Direction.

Comment: The Salary column is a number, the CONVERT will make it left-aligned. you might need to do RIGHT(SPACE(20) + FORMAT(Salary, '#.00'), 20)

Answer (score -2):

something like this should work :

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 'ASC'  THEN @SortType END ASC,
  CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN @SortType END DESC
```

Comment: Ordering by `SortType` won't work.  SQL Server doesn't allow a variable in the place of a column name.

Comment: instead of case, do we have better solution as i have 11 columns for sort type.

Comment: @Andomar No, Sql server 2008 r2 accepts it, I just tried ( just forget to put @ at the first of the names at first)

Comment: @JitendraPancholi you want them to be different in SortDirection with each other?

Comment: @MaryamArshi: It will accept it, but it won't work as you expect.  It'll sort on the constant value of `@SortType`, i.e., it won't sort at all

Comment: @MaryamArshi: yes, it won't work properly. this is what i mentioned above in my question too.

Comment: It might not work for a variable field, but it works perfectly well for a constant field if anyone wants to do that as I did, but with a variable sort direction: ORDER BY CASE WHEN @SortDesc=1 THEN DateField END DESC, CASE WHEN @SortDesc=0 THEN DateField END ASC