# Dynamic Order By clause with column and sort information coming from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2016

I have tried this (from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34970089/77712)), but it does not seem to work:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cs.ColumnName + ' ' +  cs.ColumnSort
                    FROM #ColumnSort cs
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),NULL)
```

Is something like this possible or does the entire query have to be Dynamic SQL?

I ensured the column name had a proper alias so the scheme or table name does not have to included in the `ColumnName` field.

Comment: This will sort by some sort of really weird strings with column names.  If you want the *values* in the columns, you would need dynamic SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, that is what I thought.

Comment: I'm also confused about your use of ISNULL with NULL as the second argument.  Isn't that effectively a no-op?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only work if you are using dynamic SQL. I was not able to get it to work as-is.